# how to write record names with versions properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I need bit help on below issue.

**Background:**

I have a set of array.

```
["3a67ef_V1", "3a67ef", "2b678_V1", "1b", "3a67ef_V2", "2b678_V2", "2b678"]
```

in this array i need to find the **curentRecordName** and**higher Version numeber**

I am creating a file based on record id

**For e.g:** if record id is **1** then file will be saved as **1a.json**

if user want to create another record with same name
i will write as **1a_V1.json**

**Update:** there can be other character as well besides **number**, but after **_V** there wont be other letters than numbers

**Issue:** whenever user is creating same record name file should write as

```
1a_V1.json
1a_V2.json
1a_V3.json
1a_V4.json
```

**Code goes here**

```
// current record name
var curentRecordName = '2';

//we need check curentRecordName as well as higher version in this array
var recordIDs = ["3a67ef_V1", "3a67ef", "2b678_V1", "1b", "3a67ef_V2", "2b678_V2", "2b678"];

//looping though the array
for (var m = 0; m < recordIDs.length; m++) {

    var version = +1;

    // if record exist, add record to initial version to 1
    // for e.g: if record number 4 is alreday exist then create 4_V1
    if (recordIDs[m] === curentRecordName) {
        curentRecordName = curentRecordName + '_V' + [version];
        break;
    }

    //if record version 2 exist add version 3, if version 3 exist add version 4 etc
    // i need help here please

    if (recordIDs[m] === curentRecordName + '_V' + recordIDs[m].split("_V").pop()) {

        var adddition = parseInt(recordIDs[m].split("_V").pop()) + 1;
        curentRecordName = curentRecordName + '_V' + adddition;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(curentRecordName);

//Final motive is to create _V3, _V4_, V5 in arrays
```

Once record name is added, i will save it background

```
var saveObject = {
    "alf_destination": localStorage.getItem('folderNodeRef'),
    "prop_cm_name": "report_" + recordName + ".json",
    "prop_cm_content": JSON.stringify(this.records),
    "prop_mimetype": "text/json"
};
```

*how to do this ?*

**I just want a logic how to create records by finding high version in array and adding one more bigger version.?**

**[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/zs8c2dk8/2/)**

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> by finding high version in array and adding one more bigger version

In ES6 you can do that :
https://jsfiddle.net/xjx6koda/

```
//we need check curentRecordName as well as higher version in this array
var recordIDs = ["3a67ef_V1", "3a67ef", "2b678_V1", "1b", "3a67ef_V2", "2b678_V2", "2b678"];

function getNextRecord(crn) {
    const [highestVersion] = recordIDs
        .filter(r => r.indexOf(`${crn}_V`) === 0 || crn === r)
        .map(r => (crn === r) ? 0 : parseFloat(r.replace(`${crn}_V`,'')) )
        .sort((a,b) => a < b)

    return highestVersion >= 0 ? `${crn}_V${highestVersion + 1}` : crn;
}

console.log('with 3a67ef : ', getNextRecord('3a67ef'))
// with 3a67ef :  3a67ef_V3
console.log('with new : ', getNextRecord('new'))
// with new :  new
console.log('with 1b : ', getNextRecord('1b'))
// with 1b :  1b_V1
```

Comment: Iam getting error for line  --------- 'const [curentRecord] = recordIDs.map(r => parseFloat(r.replace('_V','.')) ).sort((a,b) => a < b)' ------------- error TS2345: Argument of type '(a: number, b: number) => boolean' is not assignabl
e to parameter of type '(a: number, b: number) => number'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'. any idea?

Comment: i have updated my question with new array, please check

Comment: i have changed my response above. Tell me if it's ok for you

Comment: still same error.----- 'error' in .sort((a,b) => a < b)------, TS2345: Argument of type '(a: number, b: number) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: number, b: number) => number'.

Comment: which value do you put in entry of getNextRecord ? and what should happened when you have 11aes_V1 in the array ? How you distinguish a `1`and an `11` record

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this

```js
// current record name
var curentRecordName = '2';
//we need check curentRecordName as well as higher version in this array
var recordIDs = ["3_V1", "3", "2_V1", "1", "3_V2", "2_V2", "2"];

var possibleIDs = recordIDs.filter((data) => data.split("_")[0] == curentRecordName).sort((first, second) => {
return second.split("_V")[1] - first.split("_V")[1];
});

if (possibleIDs.length > 0) {
var data = possibleIDs[0].split("_V")[0] + "_V" + (Number(possibleIDs[0].split("_V")[0]) + 1);
recordIDs.push(data);
}
console.log(recordIDs);
```

Comment: calculation is going wrong. please change  'curentRecordName = 3', it suppose to create '3_v3' but its creating '3_v4', js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zautub83/2/